# Despliegue de proyecto Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Hola estoy desplegando mi proyecto en un servidor Linux 16.04 pero cuando hago lo siguiente 
 `python3 manage.py  collectstatic`
todo bien el problema es después cuando pongo a correr la app que no me encuentra los archivos estáticos me salen asi en consola 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi tengo conformado mi proyecto
y en el archivo settings.py tenía puesto asi 
`STATIC_URL = 'src/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'src/static')]`

y lo cambie porque me pide STATIC_ROOT

`STATIC_URL = 'src/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que tienes una confusión entre el `STATIC_URL` y el `STATIC_ROOT`, pero básicamente también debes decirle a tu `STATIC_ROOT` que los archivos están dentro de la carpeta `src`. Y al final que funcione también va a depender de qué URL está sirviendo los estáticos y obvio que tu variable `STATIC_URL` apunte a esa dirección base

Comment: Esto es porque una de las rutas está mal, enséñame lo que te muestra al correr collectstatic

Comment: si era que no tenia bien lo de los STATIC_ROOT Y STATIC_URL